# php script stopped working on php 5.4.24

Tags: php, sockets, upgrade

I have a php script that I use for work (it is a php interface for a custom image search engine that searches by image, similar to Tineye and Google Image Search). It used to work fine on php 5.2, but stopped working after the server upgrade to php 5.3 and 5.4. Here is the script Client.php:

[Client.txt](http://maga.awardspace.co.uk/Client.txt)

the script is long, I was not able to post it here, as there is a character limit, so I uploaded it as a text file with code. I wanted to show you the entire thing, because I am not sure which part causes an issue with new php version, but the problem seems to be somewhere in socket connection part.

I checked the error log, it doesn't display any php errors, and this is the problem, otherwise I would at least know where to start. It just wont connect and wont do anything. The script displays a socket connection form, then after you click "Accept and Connect" it is supposed to connect you to the server, a search form appears and you can start searching. This is how it was on php 5.2. But since my server was upgraded, it is not connecting, when you click "Accept and Connect" nothing happens, the page just refreshes itself, with no errors. I am stuck!!! I am not a programmer, but need to get it to work somehow, please help.

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site. I recommend you take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - and head back when you have a more specific programming-related question. As written, your post here is likely off-topic for StackOverflow, as it is far too broad, and you may not receive the responses you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance the php upgrade may have disabled the short_open_tag setting in the php.ini. A quick fix for this would be to change the php open tag in the script from `<?` to `<?php`.

It looks like you may be making a call to ImageMagick with the line:

```
$command = escapeShellCmd("./convert -geometry $ImgWidthx$ImgHeight $desti1 $desti2");
```

When using double quotes, PHP sees the variable `$ImgWidth` as `$ImgWidthx` which is undefined.
A quick fix would be to separate the variables with curly brackets like so.

```
$command = escapeShellCmd("./convert -geometry {$ImgWidth}x{$ImgHeight} $desti1 $desti2");
```

Hope this helps. Also, if you updated the HTML doctype on the output check for deprecated HTML in your script.

Comment: thanks so much for additional suggestions, but that's not the case. I finally figured out how to turn on Notices, not Errors. Before I was just looking in logs for errors. And this is what it says:    Notice: Undefined variable: Submit in /home/me/public_html/Client.php on line 907 But I have no idea how to define it. It refers to this line: switch ($Submit) {